# TFS 2008 build definition in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to run TFS 2008 build definition on TFS 2010?
Or maybe it is possible to convert 2008 build definition to 2010?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run a TFS 2008 build definition in TFS 2010.

You can use a [special upgrade process](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2009/11/03/upgrading-tfs-2008-build-definitions-to-tfs-2010.aspx) to allow TFS 2008 build definitions in TFS 2010.

Comment: +1. The Upgrade template allows you to run your old MSBild scripts (TFSBuild.proj files) with very little (or no) modification. We wasted days trying to figure out how to drag and drop things in the workflow system to get basic day-to-day operations (building one solution twice with different parameters, obfuscation, building installers, code signing, even just basic stuff like copying a selection of output files to a different folder) to work under workflow but it was all simply impossible (bad tools, illogical & unintuitive processes, zero documentation == crap) so we stuck with MSBuild.